# How to hide SSH username,password and private key in Jenkins

Tags: java, ssh, jenkins, automation

I am running SSH command through Java with Jsch(java library). Basically later I will integrate it with Jenkins. So I need idea to hide my SSH Username, Password and Private key from code. How we can hide SSH username and password from code?

I come across the ssh-agent-plugin but how we can retrieve the username and password stored in Jenkins to my java code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

How do you want to integrate the Java code into Jenkins ? I assume you will integrate it with the `Execute Shell` build step. If so, you can try this steps:

1. Install the [Mask Passwords Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin)
2. Setup your password from the job configuration under `Build Environment` by checked the `Mask Passwords` option and add your password. You can see your password will be masked as `*`.
   [image]
3. After that, you can reference your password variable by using `${Password}
   [image]
4. Then even in the build log, your password will be shown as `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should store login and password in credentials, then use plugin that can inject chosen credentials pair into build as variable and such injection tool ideally should allow "mask passwords".

For ssh should be available build step that allow choose credentials https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin